# Apache não carrega módulo do PHP

Tags: php, apache

Estou seguindo esse artigo para configurar o Apache e o PHP:

[Instalar e Configurar o Ambiente de Desenvolvimento em PHP - Parte 2](http://blog.patriciodossantos.net/2013/12/instalar-e-configurar-o-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-em-php-no-windows-8-2a-parte/)

Já configurei corretamente o **php.ini** e **httpd.conf** além da DLL **php5apache2_4.dll** estar em seu respectivo lugar, porém está retornando o seguinte erro na reinicialização do servidor Apache:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 531 of D:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Invalid LoadModule path \xe2\x80\xaa"D:/php-5.6.13/php5apache2_4.dll"

Procurei problemas similares no Stackoverflow mas as respostas não ajudaram.

A única diferença é que invés de colocar na partição C coloquei na partição D os arquivos do Apache além do PHP

**EDIT**

Httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module ‪"D:/php-5.6.13/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
PHPIniDir "D:/php-5.6.13/"
```

**EDIT**

Alterei o arquivo Httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module ‪"../php-5.6.13/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
PHPIniDir "../php-5.6.13/"
```

Porém agora está dando outro erro:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 531 of D:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Cannot load ../php-5.6.13/php5apache2_4.dll into server: %1 n\xe3o
>   \xe9 um aplicativo Win32 v\xe1lido.

Não é um aplicativo Win32 válido, sendo que as versões de ambos (Apache e PHP) são Win32

Comment: Tente com a *DLL*, `php5apache2_2.dll`

Comment: Arrumei o problema, obrigado @PapaCharlie, porém agora retornou outro.

Comment: Arrumei o outro problema, me enganei quando falei que a versão do Apache era Win32, agora sim que é Win32. Iniciou corretamente o servidor.